# Entity Framework exclude records from the foreign table

Tags: c#, foreign-key-relationship

I'm having a problem excluding the records from a foreign table based on a condition.

// this query returns everything from all the tables that are referenced in MainTable

```
    var query = db.MainTable.Where(x => x.ID == 123)
```

How can I exclude some of the records from one of the foreign tables based on a Status field in the foreign table?
Something like this:

```
    var query = db.MainTable.Where(x => x.ID == 123 && y => y.ForeignTable.Status == false)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a foreign key relationship placed in your object, i.e. ICollection<ForeignTable> foreignItems or public virtual ForeignTable foreignItem?

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond, yes I do.

Comment: You can probably just do a join to limit specifically.  something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896266(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-5

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you do have the correct relationships set up, and your example seems to suggest that what you have is a singular relationship (not a reference to an ICollection) you should be able to just do:

`var query = db.MainTable.Where(x => x.ID == 123 && x.ForeignTable.Status == false)`.

If you *were* using an ICollection, you'd then have to do something like this:

`var query = db.MainTable.Where(x => x.ID == 123 && x.ForeignTable.All(y => y.Status == false))`

which I *think* would work, but haven't tested.

You could also look into the [Enumerable.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.100).aspx) syntax which I have needed for some more complex joins. It can be really verbose however, and for simple joins the method above should work just fine.